# Jest unit test case for ternary operator

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, react-native, jestjs

I need advice on how to write a jest unit test to cover the following lines of code:

```
navbarHeight: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 64 : 54,
  statusBarHeight: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 16 : 0,
```

Comment: You can mock the `Platform` object to be `'ios'` or some other string value. Then expect the result based off of the mocked value.

Comment: I can get a test case to be passed for a true condition.My doubt arises in executing for the false condition. (i.e)to make the condition false and assign the value as 54 for navbarHeight.

Comment: Do the opposite of @vapurrmaid suggested, and mock the Platform to be Android.  Then run the same test code and you will get the false value returned.

Comment: Did you resolved this issue @Taarun